# Should hyphens be used at the beginning of a line in compound nouns?

Tags: formatting, punctuation

Is there a rule about using two hyphens at the end of the line and at the beginning of the next?
How to hyphen compound word like Bat-Signal?
Is it:
Bat- / -Signal
or
Bat- / Signal

Answer (score 2):

No, in English only one hyphen is used per line break (even when the word would already have a hyphen), attached to the first word part.

[Example](https://books.google.com/books?id=76hYAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Un-American%22&hl=en&newbks) with "Un-American":

[image: "Un hyphen newline American"]